# Fill row(/product) information based on product list contained in previous worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with several different worksheets. The first worksheet contains a list of products that have a unique id in the second column. The rest of the columns contain additional information for the product like Name, Price, Discount etc.

In the rest of the worksheets I'm adding products by adding their unique id and then copying and pasting the first sheet's row. What I'm basically trying to do is create a macro that will be executed when the unique id is entered in the second column of the n-th worksheet (e.g. in the 5th worksheet). It should automatically fill the rest of the columns using the information from the product with that same id in the first worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [`VLOOKUP()`](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) formula?

Given a table (simplified from your description) like this:

```
    A:     B:   C:
1:  ID1    A    Spec
2:  ID2    B    Spec
3:  ID3    C    Spec
4:  ID4    D    Spec
5:  ID5    E    Spec
```

You can use formulas like this on your following sheets:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!A1:C5,2,FALSE)
```

Where B2 is the cell containing the product number you enter. To get VBA to automate this process, create a macro that triggers on the changing of a cell:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim lChangedRow As Long
If Target.Column = 2 Then
    lChangedRow = Target.Row
    Range("D" & lChangedRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B" & lChangedRow & ",Sheet1!A1:C5,2,FALSE)"
    'Fill in additional columns (change "D") as necessary...
End If

End Sub
```

`If Target.Column = 2 Then` checks to see that the value changed is in the second column only, so that you don't have multiple runs of the update when not necessary.

`Range("D" & lChangedRow).Formula...` sets the `VLOOKUP` function highlighted at the top of this post.

`Sheet1!A1:C5` will need to be changed to match your first worksheet's name/data.

---

To avoid having to enter this code on every sheet, you can simplify by putting similar code in its own module (*this isn't necessary, but is helpful if you ever want to change the Sub, since you will only have to change it once*):

```
Public Sub FillData(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim lChangedRow As Long
    lChangedRow = Target.Row
    Range("D" & lChangedRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B" & lChangedRow & ",Sheet1!A1:C5,2,FALSE)"
    'Fill in additional columns (change "D") as necessary...
End Sub
```

With each sheet having the same, simplified code which calls the Sub:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 2 Then
        FillData(Target)
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Another non-necessity, but may be helpful, depending on your use/the size of this workbook would be to change the formulas to static values once updated. If you will be changing your data often, or if the data set is fairly small, then you probably **shouldn't** do this.

However, if you find that updating all those `VLOOKUP`s takes a good amount of time, and your data will not change once you've entered your unique ID, then this will help speed things up:

```
Public Sub FillData(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim lChangedRow As Long
    lChangedRow = Target.Row
    Range("D" & lChangedRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B" & lChangedRow & ",Sheet1!A1:C5,2,FALSE)"
    Range("D" & lChangedRow).Value = Range("D" & lChangedRow).Value
    'Fill in additional columns (change "D") as necessary...
End Sub
```